# Extra spaces being added to PHP mail headers

Tags: html-email, php, amazon-ses

I'm sending a multipart HTML email using PHP's `mail()` function. In my Postfix configuration I have my SMTP server set to Amazon's SES. Here is the PHP for sending the email:

```
$boundary = uniqid("HTMLDEMO");

$headers  = "From: me@mydomain.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary = ".$boundary."\r\n\r\n";

// plain text
$content  = "--".$boundary."\r\n" .
            "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n" .
            chunk_split(base64_encode($plaintext_message));

// HTML
$content .= "--".$boundary."\r\n" .
            "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: text/html \r\n\r\n" .
            "<html><body>".$html_message."</body></html>";

//send message
mail($to, $subject, $content, $headers);
```

When I echo the message content, this is what I see in the browser:

```
--HTMLDEMO527d8d851e72f
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

VGhpcyBpcyB0aGUgcGxhaW4gdGV4dCB2ZXJzaW9uIQ==
--HTMLDEMO527d8d851e72f
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: text/html

<html><body><p>My message here.</p></body></html>
```

But when I view the message source in Gmail, I now see this (including the message headers):

```
From: me@mydomain.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary = HTMLDEMO527d8d851e72f
Message-ID: <blah-blah-blah@email.amazonses.com>
Date: Sat, 9 Nov 2013 01:19:02 +0000
X-SES-Outgoing: 2013.11.09-12.34.5.67

--HTMLDEMO527d8d851e72f

Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64



VGhpcyBpcyB0aGUgcGxhaW4gdGV4dCB2ZXJzaW9uIQ==

--HTMLDEMO527d8d851e72f

Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

Content-Transfer-Encoding: text/html
```

The multipart headers are now double-spaced, causing the HTML to display as plain text. SES is clearly modifying the message headers (it added `Message-ID`, `Date`, and `X-SES-Outgoing`), so could that also be the culprit for the extra spaces in the multipart headers? When I send an identical email from a non-Amazon server, it comes through normally and renders the HTML like it should.

Also, when I send it as a simple HTML email (not multipart), then it works just fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Those are multipart headers, not headers in the original message. I suggest you show us your PHP code. Also, what happens when you try a different SMTP server?

Answer (score 0):

I had got the same issue and I resolved it by changing the end of line character to '\n' instead of '\r\n'.